# Отправить AJAX запрос на другой домен

Tags: javascript, ajax

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.withCredentials = true;
req.open('GET', 'http://example.com/api/method', true);
req.addEventListener('load', function() {
  console.log(req.responseText)
});
req.onerror = function() {
 console.log('Ошибка ' + this.status);
}
req.send();
```

Как сделать чтобы работало?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если смотреть ваш код, то никак. 
Ограничение origin policy в браузерах, можно вроде как-то включать в браузере, но об этом забудьте. Есть несколько вариантов:

1. Отправка на сервер с общим поддоменом, site1.parentdomain.com <> site2.parentdomain.com
2. Посмотрите JSONP.
3. Если первые два варианта не подходят, то остаётся наверно только проксирование запроса на своём сервере.
   Все решения подробны описаны в интернете.